# Why not implement `let` in terms of lexically closed `define`?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I have been working with lisp-family languages for several years and feel like I have a pretty good grasp on them. I'm now writing my own lisp (as is the fashion, of course), but almost entirely avoiding re-implementing the same patterns that Scheme, Common Lisp and friends have used. One particular thing that I always found odd was all the variants of `let` (`letrec`, `flet`, `labels`, `let*`...).

Say in a "no legacy carried over from the past" implementation of a lisp, I'd like to just be able to write things like:

```
(let ((x 7)
      (y 8)
      (z (* x y)))
  (str "x * y * z = " (* x y z)))
```

And similarly I'd like to be able to write:

```
(let ((odd? (lambda (n) (if (zero? n) false (even? (dec n)))))
      (even? (lambda (n) (if (zero? n) true (odd? (dec n)))))
  (odd? 7))
```

I could implement both of those variants quite efficiently by just using define inside the body of a lambda. Excuse the clojure-scheme-hybrid code:

```
(defmacro let (bindings & body)
  `((lambda ()
      ,@(map (lambda (name-value) (cons 'define name-value)) bindings)
      ,@body)))
```

Because this just introduces the bindings within the closed environment in the body of the lambda, mutual recursion can work and variables can depend on the existence of previous definitions. Similarly, because a lambda closes the environment in which it is created, expanding the `(define x expression) (define y expression)` works as expected.

So why complicate matters by having numerous explicit forms? Am I overlooking something? I have implement my own `let` as I demonstrate above and it seems to work in all cases exactly as expected. This also reduces the cost overhead of nested function applications, such as in the case of `let*`.

Comment: nested `define`s do not "just" work so you could define stuff with them. nested `define`s are _implemented_ themselves through the use of `letrec`. without that, you'd have to implement the nested `define`s yourself in your language, quite possibly mimicking the `letrec` behavior (with the destructive mutation of the shared internal environment and whatnot ... which is maybe what you thought `define`s already do. they don't.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Internal definitions are defined (har har) by R5RS to use `letrec`, and by R6RS and R7RS to use `letrec*`. The behaviour you're describing is exactly what `letrec*` is.

However, there are cases where you want to use the outer bindings, and you don't want the inner bindings to shadow them during their definitions. In this case, `let` and `let*` are more appropriate than `letrec` and `letrec*`.

What do I mean by this? Here's one way that `let` provides outer scoping that `letrec` doesn't:

```
(let ((x 1)
      (y 2))
  (let ((x (+ x y))
        (y (- x y)))
    (format #t "x = ~a, y = ~a~%" x y)))
```

Here, in the `(+ x y)` and `(- x y)` expressions, we are using the *outer* bindings of `x` and `y`. Thus the inner `x` will be 3, and the inner `y` will be -1.

Using `let*` is similar except that the bindings are sequential:

```
(let ((x 1)
      (y 2))
  (let* ((x (+ x y))
         (y (- x y)))
    (format #t "x = ~a, y = ~a~%" x y)))
```

Here, the inner `x` is evaluated the same as for the `let` case, but the inner `y`'s definition will use the inner `x` instead of the outer `x` (but it still uses the outer `y`, as the inner `y` hasn't been bound yet). Thus the inner `x` will be 3, and the inner `y` will be 1.

When using `letrec` and `letrec*`, all the outer bindings will be shadowed by the inner bindings of the same name, and you do not have access to the outer `x` or `y` in those cases. This property is what allows their use for self-referential functions and/or data structures.

`letrec` and `letrec*` are similar, except that for `letrec`, the values are all evaluated first, then bound to the variables at the end, simultaneously; whereas for `letrec*`, the values for each variable are evaluated and bound sequentially from left to right.

---

To demonstrate the four `let` types, I wrote a little Racket macro that allows you to test the behaviour of each:

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax test-let
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ let)
     (let ((x "outer x")
           (y "outer y")
           (p (lambda (x y label)
                (printf "~a: x = ~s, y = ~s~%" label x y))))
       (let ((before (p x y "before"))
             (x (begin
                  (p x y "during x")
                  "inner x"))
             (between (p x y "between"))
             (y (begin
                  (p x y "during y")
                  "inner y"))
             (after (p x y "after")))
         (p x y "body"))))))
```

And the test results:

```
> (test-let let)
before: x = "outer x", y = "outer y"
during x: x = "outer x", y = "outer y"
between: x = "outer x", y = "outer y"
during y: x = "outer x", y = "outer y"
after: x = "outer x", y = "outer y"
body: x = "inner x", y = "inner y"

> (test-let let*)
before: x = "outer x", y = "outer y"
during x: x = "outer x", y = "outer y"
between: x = "inner x", y = "outer y"
during y: x = "inner x", y = "outer y"
after: x = "inner x", y = "inner y"
body: x = "inner x", y = "inner y"

> (require rnrs/base-6)
> (test-let letrec)
before: x = #<undefined>, y = #<undefined>
during x: x = #<undefined>, y = #<undefined>
between: x = #<undefined>, y = #<undefined>
during y: x = #<undefined>, y = #<undefined>
after: x = #<undefined>, y = #<undefined>
body: x = "inner x", y = "inner y"

> (require rnrs/base-6)
> (test-let letrec*)
before: x = #<undefined>, y = #<undefined>
during x: x = #<undefined>, y = #<undefined>
between: x = "inner x", y = #<undefined>
during y: x = "inner x", y = #<undefined>
after: x = "inner x", y = "inner y"
body: x = "inner x", y = "inner y"
```

Hopefully this will make the differences between the `let` types pretty obvious. :-)

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Indeed the behaviour in my implementation does exactly as you describe with the inner y. That said, due to the way I'm organizing my environments as linked-lists, I was planning to add support for explicit lexical scope rebinding (i.e. add a syntactic way to get variable x from the outer scope, or the outer of the outer scope etc), so this doesn't concern me much.

Comment: @d11wtq I've added some tests that demonstrate the differences between the `let` types. You should decide which variant your `let` abides by. (Note: `#<undefined>` means inner, but value not yet bound.)

Comment: Notice also, that in all cases, "before" and "during x" have the same results and "between" and "during y" have the same results, but "after" and "body" have the same results only for `let*` and `letrec*`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Super helpful. I'm drawn to digest this in detail now, but should really be working, so I'll come back and re-read it shortly :)

Answer (score 2):

`define` inside a procedure (or let. since it's the same) is a `letrec` until R5RS and a `letrec*` from R6RS and the current R7RS. You can do everything with `letrec*` except overshadow your own variables (they become undefined).

```
(let ((x 10))
  (letrec ((x x))
     x)) ;; returns some undefined value
```

becomes

```
(let ((x 10))
  (let ((x 'undefined))
     (let ((tmpx x)) ;; notice x is already shadowed by the new binding
        (set! x tmpx)
        x))) ;; returns some undefined value
```

The reason for that is because the evaluation of the variables needs to be done while the variable already is defined so that it can recurse. Your mutually recursive `odd?` depends on it. While two lets in the same way sets the new x to the old x since they never exist at the same time.

As you probably know `(let ((x 10) (y 20)) ...)` is nothing more than syntax sugar for an anonymous procedure call `((lambda (x y) ...) 10 20)`, `let*` is nested let `(let* ((x 10) (y 20)) ...)  => (let ((x 10)) (let ((y 20)) ... )))`. A named `let` is a `letrec` and a `letrec*` is almost nested `letrec` (All the variables are made in the same let to uninitialized values so that all the levels can reference to them)

If you want to bind 10 variables and can do it in one closure it's the cheapest while doing it with `define` introduces 20 procedure calls and 10 mutations. It's probably nothing a modern interpreter can manage today but Scheme didn't perform that good back when it was invented and would do worse if it only had `letrec*`

Comment: A `letrec*` is not the same as a nested `letrec`. You can refer to later variables in a `letrec*` during the definition of an earlier variable (in the same `letrec*` expression), they just won't be bound at the time (whereas with `letrec`, they won't be bound at all until all the binding values have been evaluated). You can formulate the mutually-recursive `odd?` and `even?` functions using `letrec*`, but you can't do it using nested `letrec`s.

Comment: That's interesting, since in my implementation, your first example will return 10. I haven't followed the convention of "let a value be void, then mutate it in scope", instead just having `define` create new variables in the current environment with a single call. My lisp isn't implemented in lisp/scheme itself, so I'm using the features of my implementation language to simplify things.

Comment: @d11wtq How would your `let` allow the 10 to happen while still allowing recursive expressions to be defined in the same way? Remember that the outer `x` and inner `x` are different variables and point to different locations.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young So all the variabes are allocated in one `let` before you have nested `tmp` and `set!`. It's needed for mutually recursiveness to work right. I'll update :)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young unless I'm missing something, mine does work with recursive expressions and variable shadowing at the same time. I'm testing it now. I have probably misunderstood the scenario where it should break though.

Comment: @d11wtq What do you get when you do this: `(let ((x 10) (y 20)) (let ((x y) (y x)) (list x y)))`. Scheme results in `(20 10)`

Comment: Ah, I see. I haven't got to this point yet, but in mine the syntax for that would be more explicit (syntax undecided): `(let ((x 10) (y 20)) (let ((x (outer y)) (y (outer x))) (list x y))`

Comment: @d11wtq Okay, in that case, how would you implement `outer`? It sounds like its implementation would be gnarly.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young my environment is actually represented as a linked list of dictionaries, so it is quite simply: `environment().outer().lookup(symbol)` (in pseudo code). `lookup()` in the implementation language looks for `symbol` in its own environment, and if it is not there, it proxies the call to the `outer()` environment and so on. So explicitly going directly to the `outer()` environment is trivial.

Comment: It's effectively analogous to dynamic method dispatch in an OO language and asking for `parent.method()` or whatever syntax your OO language uses.

Comment: @d11wtq So effectively, it can only be implemented as a builtin special form (and not as a macro, for example). Deus ex machina and all that. :-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young yes, that is correct: `(outer ...)` would be a special form that evaluates the expressions in the body in the outer scope. It's a bit weird, I know, but I'm just enjoying experimenting with this sort of stuff.

Comment: @d11wtq So with a method to reference variables not in current frame you can indeed do a `letrec*` where all bounded procedures points at the same environment frame so that it's not more expensive than a `let` by having extra syntax to access previous frame. I like it. Are you going to support `(outer (outer x))` too perhaps?

Comment: no nested `letrec`s are needed for `letrec*`. `letrec*` is almost like `letrec`, period.  :)

Comment: @WillNess False. The question is not Scheme-specific, so there can be other style. In fact, [RnRK](https://ftp.cs.wpi.edu/pub/techreports/pdf/05-07.pdf) defines its `$letrec*` in terms of `$letrec` exactly (and its derivation has explicit environment mutation), rendering a far simpler and cleaner specification than R7RS (in particular, there is no need of the artificial `<undefined>`, which is even more problematic in the derivation of `letrec`). There is also no need of `outer`. With `($define! let $let)`, `(let ((x 10) (y 20)) (let ((x y) (y x)) (list x y)))`  also evaluates to `(20 10)`.

Comment: @Sylwester Both referring to the same environment and not are easily to support once the language has first-class environments with appropriate name resolution rules in linked parent environments (e.g. by DFS). Differentiate between `let`/`letrec` with `let*`/`letrec*` is even more important here, since the current environment for the body and for other expressions being evaluated can be quite different and directly observable by the program with operations on the environments (e.g. the result of evaluation of the Kernel expression `(get-current-environment)`).

Comment: @FrankHB my comment was directed at this answer and its author, not the question. this answer uses Scheme and only Scheme. thanks for the link. in that language, does `letrec*` support mutual recursion? what does `(letrec* ((a (lambda () (b))) (b (lambda () 7))) (a))` return? Looks like it should fail... (in `r6rs` it returns `7`)

Comment: @WillNess Scheme's `letrec*` also does not rule out the possibility to the nested-`letrec` approach. The normative specification in R7RS contains no syntax expanded forms, although in the formal (but informative) derivations it uses `let` and some flavors of actual implementations like [this](https://legacy.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/fixing-letrec.pdf). It may require other magics to remain the current behavior precisely.

Comment: @WillNess As of your case, the Kernel's `$letrec*` would fail for unbound symbol `b` as expected, which is pointed out by the _Rational_ section for `$letrec*` in RnRK: "no way for combiners resulting from different binding expressions to be _mutually_ recursive". This weakening of the `$letrec` is expected.

Comment: @WillNess There are other features in Kernel make it easy to implement `letrec*` in RnRS-style. To name a few, there are operative combiners, [explicit `eval`](https://ftp.cs.wpi.edu/pub/techreports/pdf/08-01.pdf) and structural bindings (making multiple symbols bound in the same time, which is the key for simpler `$letrec` derivation). These are magics to Scheme (not trivially implementable by a meta-circular evaluator instead of writing an ordinary interpreter). The RnRS-style `letrec*` seems not _that_ interesting unless it is the core IR for the compiler, which is an implementation detail.

Comment: @FrankHB does Kernel have any possibility to define mutually recursive functions?

Comment: @WillNess `$letrec` (not `$letrec*`) has already satisfied the usual criteria of defining mutually recursive functions. And even with `$letrec*`, it can do the same by defining more than one symbols in the same _binding_ clause, which is not possible in Scheme.

Comment: A few cases in Kernel: (1) `($letrec ((a ($lambda () (b))) (b ($lambda () 7))) (a))` => `7`;
(2) `($letrec* ((a ($lambda () (b))) (b ($lambda () 7))) (a))` => fail;
(3) `($letrec (((a b) (list ($lambda () (b)) ($lambda () 7)))) (a))` => 7;
(4) `($letrec* (((a b) (list ($lambda () (b)) ($lambda () 7)))) (a))` => 7;
(5) `($let (((a b) (list ($lambda () (b)) ($lambda () 7)))) (a))` => fail;
(6) `($let* (((a b) (list ($lambda () (b)) ($lambda () 7)))) (a))` => fail.

Comment: Sorry, the link for explicit `eval` above is wrong. The correct one is [here](https://web.wpi.edu/Pubs/ETD/Available/etd-090110-124904/unrestricted/jshutt.pdf). The term _explicit evaluation_ is mentioned in section 1.2.3.3 (by avoiding `quote`). `eval` is a combiner defined in the source language, which implements this style with first-class environments. (Scheme also has `eval`, but the argument to provide the environment is significantly limited, and its uses are even not encouraged for most cases.)