# Racket let, some doubts

Tags: racket

```
(let ((+ *)
      (* +))
  (+ 3 (* 4 5)))
```

Output: 27

```
(let ((+ *))
  (+ 3 (* 4 5)))
```

Output: 60

I don't understand how `let` works. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Need More clarification to your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**let**

`let` binds in *parallel* because

```scm
(let ((+ *) (* +))
  (+ 3 (* 4 5)))
```

actually expands to

```scm
((lambda (+ *) 
   (+ 3 (* 4 5))) 
 * +)
```

so Scheme does its usual thing:

1. the parameters `*` and `+` are evaluated to their respective values (the procedures `*` and `+`) in *some* sequence
2. then bound to the formal parameters `+` and `*` (this also happens in *some* sequence, but it doesn't matter which in both cases)
3. then the body of the inner function is evaluated as `(* 3 (+ 4 5))`.

Just add a `printf` to confirm:

```scm
(let ((+ *) (* +))
  (printf "+ is ~a and * is ~a \n" + *)
  (+ 3 (* 4 5)))

=> 
+ is #<procedure:*> and * is #<procedure:+> 
27
```

**let***

If you expect the binding to happen in *sequence*, then you have to use *let** since

```scm
(let* ((+ *) (* +))
  (+ 3 (* 4 5)))
```

expands to

```scm
((lambda (+) 
   ((lambda (*) 
      (+ 3 (* 4 5))) 
    +))
 *)
```

so

1. `*` is bound to `+`
2. then `+` which has already be bound to `*`, is bound to `*` again so this actually has no effect
3. then the expression becomes `(* 3 (* 4 5))`

and since the second binding has no effect this is equivalent to simply

```scm
(let ((+ *))
  (+ 3 (* 4 5)))
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you could replaced the bound `+` and `*` by `plus` and `times`, I think it would have been clearer.

Comment: @Metaxal Thanks! Maybe but then it wouldn't match the question... I'll happily elaborate if the OP wants to have more details at any level.

Comment: @Metaxal If you used `plus` and `times`, it would totally negate the question. The OP seems to be wondering why the inner `+` didn't apply to the definition of the inner `*`.

Comment: @both: That's precisely the point: If you replace the `+` bound in the `let` by `plus`, you show that the second `+` in the `let` bindings is not the same, and so remains `+`. That's just identifier renaming to show which identifiers are the same.

Comment: @Metaxal I agree with uselpa and C J-Y here, but I *do* think that showing `(let ((plus *) (* plus)) …)` or `(let ((+ times) (times +)) …)` could be useful because the unbound variable error will more clearly demonstrate the scope of the bindings.  The scope issue in the original code is complicated by the fact that `*` and `+` already have bindings outside the `let`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first expression, `*` is bound to the original value of `+`, and `+` is bound to the original value of `*`. Thus `(+ 3 (* 4 5))` would be equivalent to `(* 3 (+ 4 5))` with the original bindings. That is the same as the infix expression `3 * (4 + 5)`, which is of course 27.

In the second expression, `+` is bound to the original value of `*` and `*` is unchanged. Thus `(+ 3 (* 4 5))` would be equivalent to `(* 3 (* 4 5))` with the original bindings, which is the same as the infix expression `3 * (4 * 5)`, which is 60.

The most important note here is that `let` does *parallel* binding. That means in an expression like `(let ((+ *) (* +)) ...)`, the original values of `*` and `+` are taken first, and then `+` and `*` are bound *simultaneously*. That is why the new `*` has the *old* value of `+`, not its new value.

I recently wrote [a post about the differences between the various `let` forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22548692/13). Note the difference between `let` and `let*`, in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Stepper!

Racket has a nice stepper that can help answer this question for you. Paste your code into a buffer, change to the "Intermediate Student" Language, and click the "step" button. You'll see a highlighted sequence of steps.

Answer (score -1):

Because this:

```
(let ((+ *)
      (* +))
  (+ 3 (* 4 5)))
```

is strictly equivalent to (this is called identifier renaming):

```
(let ((PLUS *)
      (TIMES +))
  (PLUS 3 (TIMES 4 5)))
```

because, as the other answers point out, the bindings are done in parallel.
This means that the expression that is actually evaluated here is:

```
(* 3 (+ 4 5))
```

which is indeed 27.